# Java delaying frame repainting

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to animate the solution of my 16 puzzle application and I am open to suggestions of how to use the Timer class. Currently the animation happens really fast and only the final state gets displayed. I tried increasing the delay to 3000ms but the outcome was the same.

```
public void animateSolution(Node node)
{
    Stack<Node> solution = new Stack<>();

    while (node != null)
    {
        solution.push(node);
        node = node.getParent();
    }


    while (!solution.isEmpty())
    {
        Node current = solution.pop();

        Timer timer = new Timer(750, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                moveBuilder(current);
                repaint();

            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to create a distinct `Timer` at each iteration of your loop.

Consider using a single `Timer` and get rid of the second `while` loop, like e.g :

```
Timer timer = new Timer(750, new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(!solution.isEmpty()){

            Node current = solution.pop();
            moveBuilder(current);
            repaint();
        }


    }
});

timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

Note that for this anonymous class to work with `solution`, you will have to declare `solution` as `final` :

```
final Stack<Node> solution = new Stack<>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually even worked without making solution final.